# SPGridView and SP Menufield for approving list items from SPlist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using spgridview for showing listdata,also using spmenufield.

I need to perform approve operation on any selected/clicked item from spgridview.

Can you please help,how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no options to directly Approve the items using the SPMenuField, what you can do is to write up a JavaScript call that will get the details of the Item and redirect to the default Approval Page.

By default SharePoint approval page will be of format

_layouts/approve.aspx?List={F723A0FD-9072-46C6-A4B6-BBB21538CB68}&ID=112

Refer to [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/powlo/archive/2007/02/25/displaying-custom-data-through-sharepoint-lists-using-spgridview-and-spmenufield.aspx) for more details on SPGridView

Comment: Thanks for your answer...

It takes me to correct approve.aspx with list item reference.

Can you also help me to identify parameter required to pass for approving?

Because wht I am looking for reducing no of click to approve list item.I guess process u mention takes 2 mouse clicks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you already have the code set up so all you need to do is update the list item.

To approve the item, update the `_ModerationStatus` to `0`.

Or, I believe you can use the API (simply wraps the above into the [SPModerationInformation class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spmoderationinformation.aspx)):

```
SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
item.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
item.Update();
```